# Remove straight lines from an image

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to remove the lines from my image, it would be easy and I could just erode them to death then dilate but some letters are empty so I can't do that.

```
"""Importing the modules"""
import cv2
import numpy as np

"""Importing the image and resizing it"""
BASE_IMG = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\usr\Documents\Python\Projects\CaptchaSolver\captcha.png")
BASE_IMG = cv2.resize(BASE_IMG, (480, 360))
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\usr\Documents\Python\Projects\CaptchaSolver\captcha.png", 
cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img, (480, 360))

"""Converting it to binary image and trying my best to get rid of the lines"""
_, img = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = ~img
img = cv2.erode(img, np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8), iterations=2)
img = cv2.dilate(img, (5, 5), iterations = 3)
img = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100, edges=1)

cv2.imshow("Base", BASE_IMG)
cv2.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

You can ask for more details if you want

Comment: You’re trying to hack a CAPTCHA?

Comment: If you could provide the file of the image you used, that would be great, for we could try it out ourselves. You have only provided a combined image though. Place the image you used at the end of the question.

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches can be to do edge detection, applying Hough Transform and then create a mask for `cv2.inpaint` method. Below is the code for this approach:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('input.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,2]
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edged, 1, np.pi/180, 90)

height, width = image.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),3)

output = cv2.inpaint(image, mask, 3, flags=cv2.INPAINT_NS)

cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And the output:

[image]